# Import Data from a page with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I have a web application in react, and I have two registration page, one user and the next where you register a project, I need to get the user id that was registered on the previous page to register the project on the next page.

but I can't import the id because it's inside a function, so I can't get it

```
export default function Register({ history }) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [passwd, setPasswd] = useState('');

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const response = await api.post('/createUser',  {
            username, email, passwd,
        });

        console.log(response.data);
        const { _id: _idUser } = response.data;

        history.push(`/freela/${_idUser}`);
    }
```

I'm trying to import like this

```
import { _idUser } from './Register';
```

And he returns me this error:
[image: print]

Routes: 
[image: Routes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking that you are using `react-router` or `react-router-dom` for navigation.

For both the libraries you can pass some data as props for the next component like this in your case -

`history.push(`/freela/${_idUser}`, _idUser);`

and in your next component you can access it by

`props.location.state`

But the best way is to get it from params since you have that id in your url.

By using the `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom`;

Link to an example - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: I used getParams, but it returns me an empty variable, I also tried the method you said about props, but it also told me that props was not set, do I need to import something?

About useParams, I put it like this:
    const { _idUser } = useParams();

Comment: @LuísGustavo Can you show me how have you set the route for this particular one?

Comment: added a print to the post

Comment: I managed to get or id, but doing a trick, use split to separate in /, and the id is always in position 4, I think this is not the best format, but it was the only one that worked, can help me do the correct way, grateful !!

Comment: @LuísGustavo You can get your id by `{ id } = useParams();`

Answer (score 1):

Quick suggestion: since you are pushing `idUser` in `history.push('/freela/${_idUser}`, you can probably extract `_idUser` from the URL